# Running PowerShell Command Directly On CMD Gives Index Was Out Of Range Error

Tags: windows, powershell, command

The command below is designed to list expired user accounts:

```
powershell -c "Get-LocalUser | Where-Object { $_.AccountExpires -le (Get-Date) -and $null -ne $_.AccountExpires } | Select-Object Name, AccountExpires"
```

Running directly on PowerShell seems to run fine, however, when I run the same command via CMD, it gives the error below:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index').
```

I believe the issue is related to the $null parameter but I need this to exclude blank matches from the output. Does anyone know a way of fixing this error? Or an alternative method to no match blank output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make things clear when using operators:

```
powershell -c "Get-LocalUser | Where-Object { ($_.AccountExpires -le (Get-Date)) -and ($null -ne $_.AccountExpires) } | Select-Object Name, AccountExpires"
```

This works fine for me

Comment: Thank you, I seem to be getting the same error. Anytime I remove the $null bit it works okay. Any chance we can implement a similar check to $null?

Answer (score 1):

It might not be **$null**, try an empty string instead:

**("" -ne $_.AccountExpires)**

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have tried that option, however, PowerShell does not seem to respect it and still outputs lines that contain blank space within the account expires column.

Comment: Did some research on the property `AccountExpires`. It's a `System.Nullable[datetime]` so go ahead and try this as the operator:

`$_.AccountExpires -ne [nullable[datetime]]$null`